# Getting text from a funky span object in html

Tags: python, soap, beautifulsoup

I need to get the text from a span with no id, class or name tag but from a custom tag like so

```
<span itemprop="name">the text i Need</span>
```

I have tried as fallows:

```
def handle_data(data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    info = soup.find('span',itemprop="name").text
    return(info)
```

But all I get is just get a blank screen 
Using beautiful soap with python on the web.
any help? thanks!

Comment: It seems to be working for me. Are you sure that data is correct?

Comment: Also you don't need the () around what you are returning.

Comment: Which version of beautifulsoup are you using?

Comment: Hope this blog post might be useful to somebody regarding this. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use the 'contents' property instead of 'text':

```
info = soup.find('span', itemprop='name').contents
```